# How do I convert an improper fraction to a mixed number in Java?

Tags: java, fractions

I'm attempting the ccc j4 or s2 for the 2002 challenge.  I currently have a function to simplify the fraction, but it gives it as a mixed number.  The output of that function is a string, and I think I need another function to convert it into a mixed number. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

This is the function I used for converting:

```java
public static long gcm(long a, long b) {
  return b == 0 ? a : gcm(b, a % b);
}

public static String asFraction(long a, long b) {
  long gcm = gcm(a, b);
  return (a / gcm) + "/" + (b / gcm);
}
```

It outputs an improper fraction, but I want a mixed number. How can I get this? P.S. English is not my first language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since this is part of a challenge, I'll refrain from providing the exact answer, but what I'd focus on is this: A mixed number is an integer followed by a proper fraction. You have an improper fraction. How do you convert improper fractions to mixed numbers?

Let's take a simple example, say, `11/4`. How would we write this as a mixed fraction? We'd write `2 3/4`, because:

- `2` is the largest integer smaller than 11/4.
- `2` is 8/4, leaving 3/4 for the proper fraction.
- Thus the integer part is `2` and the proper fraction is `3/4`, giving us the answer.

So, given an improper fraction `n/d`, one way to get a mixed number is to take `k = floor[n/d]`, and return `k + (n - kd)/d`.

Hope that helps!